# socat: Is it possible to pass the received message at server side (unix domain socket) for a function?

Tags: shell

I want to implement a simple client/server (UNIX DOMAIN socket) using socat, I need to call a function (e.g: func_handle) whenever a msg is received at the server side, passing the received message as parameter.

I tried the following

### (server side):

```
#!/bin/bash 
set -ex
declare -r haproxy_sock="/var/run/haproxy/haproxy-master.sock"                                           
if [ -S "$haproxy_sock" ]; then                                                                          
    rm "$haproxy_sock"                                                                                   
fi                                                                                                       
function handle_func() {   
   echo $1
   # do something 
}
socat UNIX-LISTEN:${haproxy_sock},fork - | handle_func
```

### Client side:

```
echo "reload" | socat /var/run/haproxy/haproxy-master.sock -
```

I'm getting the following error whenever I send a message from the client side.

```
+ declare -r haproxy_sock=/var/run/haproxy/haproxy-master.sock
+ '[' -S /var/run/haproxy/haproxy-master.sock ']'
+ socat UNIX-LISTEN:/var/run/haproxy/haproxy-master.sock,fork -
+ handle_func 
+ echo 

2019/06/16 11:15:54 socat[71366] E write(1, 0x5615507b8bd0, 7): Broken pipe
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The function `handle_func` doesn't read from stdin, so it executes `echo $1` and exits. You may want to read from the input:

```
handle_func() {   
   while read -r line; do
       echo "Read: $line"
   done
}
```

Because you don't read from stdin, the stdin "pipe" is closed, so from the `socat` point of view it's "broken".

But note that when doing `socat .... - | func` the output will go to your server side stdout. So you won't be able to send anything to the client.

Just go with:

```
export -f handle_func
socat ... system:'bash -c handle_func'
```

that way the `echo "READ: $line"` from handle_func will be visible on client.

Note: the syntax `function name()` [should never be used](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete). Just go with `name()` without `function` keyword.

Example:

Server script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# server.sh
set -x

handle_func() {
  while read -r line; do
          echo "The client sended: $line" >&2
          if [ "$line" = hello ]; then
                  echo "Answering with 'world!'" >&2
                  echo 'world!'
         fi
 done
}

export -f handle_func
socat UNIX-LISTEN:${haproxy_sock},fork system:"bash -c handle_func"
```

Server side output:

```
+ export -f handle_func
+ socat UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/haproxy-master.sock,fork 'system:bash -c handle_func'
The client sended: hello
Answering with 'world!'
^C
```

Client side output:

```
$ echo "hello" | socat /tmp/haproxy-master.sock -
world!
```